# how to install canova using Maven(I am trying install nd4j for deep learning algorithms)

Tags: java, maven, deep-learning

I am trying to use the commercial version of deep learning for java  here , http://deeplearning4j.org/, during the process I need to install ND4j, the scientific computing for Java, in it I face problem at here:

Installing Canova
Take the same steps to install Canova using Maven that you followed for ND4J.

But I am new to Maven and new to Canova, did not find any solutions on how to use Maven to install Canova in ubuntu terminal, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install everything with one line of bash:

```
git clone https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/; cd deeplearning4j;./setup.sh
```

if you have questions, please join us on Gitter:

http://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j